# Regex that Detects specific string pattern

Tags: ios, regex

I'm new to Regex. The question asks me, Come up with a Regex that Detects specific string whether in start, middle or end of a string with Regular Expressions?
Try it yourself before checking the solution below:

I first thought the solution would be this:

```
  (?:^\s+)|(?:\s+$)
```

The solution is this:

```
  (?:\s|_)ra(?:\s|_)
```

How does this Regex work?

Can you walk me through each step? 
What does this line of Regex do? Please help me out.

Comment: If all you need to match is "a specific string whether in the start, middle, or end of a string", why not just use the literal substring that you're looking for?

Comment: Provide an example of what you are trying to mach, bothe the entire string and also what should be matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find answer to my question.  I will close the post now.